# How to save a contact's phone number in the administrator's Contacts component?

Tags: administrator, contact

I can not find in the admin section where the phone number in the "contact us" section changes.

Comment: I am confused about how you could not find the Telephone field in the Contact Editor.  I mean, it is the first/default tab.  Is there something that you are not telling us?

Answer (score 2):

If you have created a Joomla menu that goes directly to a single contact such as the following:

[image: Contact Menu]

Then you will need to update the contact's phone number through the contact component:

`components/contacts/[the contact selected in the menu]`

[image: Contact]